# Spring AOP Introductions usage with JMX

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, jmx, aspect

I am using Spring JMX support in order to expose the MBeans. Furthermore, to separate out the JMX code base, I am trying to use AOP's Introductions support which will allow me to take out the JMX related methods from the business POJOs and modularize them separately in JMX related Aspects.
While JMX support and AOP's introductions are working for me but when used in tandem, the JMX related methods introduced in the Aspect aren't being exposed in the MBeans.

Is this achievable through Spring? or is there any other cleaner way to have my beans JMX enabled and also not mingle the JMX-related concerns with my core code?